# Supervised PCA with caret

Tags: regression, classification, pca, supervised-learning, caret

I am trying to create my own training model in caret to do prediction using [Supervised Principal Components](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/spca_JASA.pdf), but I am having difficulty in preprocessing my data. As far as I know, I am not able to create my own preProcess function, so I am trying to process my data within the "fit" and "predict" components of my model.

The gist is that for each feature of my data model, I compute a scaled regression coefficient and then only keep those features whose absolute coefficient value falls above some threshold (a parameter in my model). I then use this reduced $X$ to compute the first $n$ principal components and fit the subsequent model. The fit component looks like this:

```
pcaFit <- function(x, y, wts, param, lev, last, weights, classProbs, ...) {

  ## Get scaled coeff vals
  coeff.values <- apply(x, 2, function(x) (t(x) %*% y) / sqrt((t(x) %*% x)))

  ## Find loadings of X
  loadings <- which(abs(coeff.values) > param$threshold)

  ## Keep nonzero loadings in X
  pc <- prcomp(x[, loadings])$x[, 1:param$nloadings]

  ## Create data frame, perform lm, return
  dat <- as.data.frame(pc)
  dat$.outcome <- y

  out <- lm(.outcome ~ ., data = dat, ...)

  out
}
```

Now, in order to do prediction, I need to keep those same loadings in my newdata, find the first $n$ principal components, and then predict with the model created above. I can't just recompute the loadings for newdata either, as these will most likely not be the same on the left-out data. For my predict function, I have something like this:

```
pcaPredict <- function(modelFit, newdata, submodels = NULL) {

  ## Add 1 to loadings to not remove "Y"
  new.x <- newdata[, 1 + loadings]
  new.y <- newdata[, 1]
  new.pc <- prcomp(new.x)$x[, 1:param$nloadings]
  newdata <- data.frame(new.pc)
  newdata$.outcome <- new.y

  out <- predict(modelFit, newdata)
  out
}
```

I've tried setting `loading` to be a global variable, but I'm not particularly well versed in how to do that effectively. When doing so, I get warnings for locked binding, etc., and that's not a path I probably want to go down unless I have to.

In short, I want to be able to get the column indices (`loadings`) found in the "fit" part of my model, and use them to preprocess the `newdata` before running prediction on it. I'm not sure how to update this value in both places, and as far as I'm aware, there isn't a preProcess function that I can use to help with this step.

Edit: After some investigating, I have found something close to what I want to do. Using sbf/sbfControl, for any particular function used (i.e., `caretSBF`), there is a

```
caretSBF$filter = function(score, x, y) score <= 0.05
```

I believe that I can update the `score` function to perform univariate feature selection based on my criterion above, but this value in `caretSBF$filter` is what I would like to tune over. Any help with that would be GREATLY appreciated.